# Button click event in DataTemplate cannot load

Tags: c#, wpf

After I add in `ContentPresenter`, `Click="btnAdd_Click"` in the `GridViewColumn` is giving me null exception error and the windows is not able to load.

WPF:

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}">
        <ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
               <Grid>
                    <ListView Name="productList" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ProductList}" Height="200">
                        <ListView.View>
                            <GridView>
                                <GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                                                <DataTemplate>
                                                                    <StackPanel Orientation ="Horizontal">
                                                                        <Button x:Name="btnOfflineAdd" 
                                                                    Tag="{Binding Index}"
                                                                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                                                    VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                                                                    FontFamily="Segoe WP" 
                                                                    Content="+"
                                                                    Height="30" Width="25"
                                                                    Click="btnAdd_Click" />
                                                                    </StackPanel>
                                                                </DataTemplate>
                                                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                                        </GridViewColumn>
                    ...
                </Grid>
            </DatTemplate>
            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ProductList.Count}" Value="0">
                     <Setter TargetName="productList" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    <Setter TargetName="productListEmpty" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
    </ContentPresenter>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a controls inside a `ContentPresenter` won't be hit at mouse event..Please refer to [this answer](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/c22ebb2e-cb27-4ae3-bfe4-8f66f8a5e9f2)

Comment: Tried, the window still fail to load.

Comment: OK. I get what you mean, I have no idea to figure out.